# Why is the following sentence in inversion style wrong?

Tags: inversion, negative-inversion

> - 1- Hadn’t he seen the car coming?
> - 2- <s>Hadn’t he seen the car coming, he would have been killed.</s>
> - 3- Had he not seen the car coming, he would have been killed.

Why is the sentence number 2, in inversion-condition sentence, wrong?

[page number 4(point 7)](https://mariabiezma.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/biezmarevised.pdf)

Comment: Who told you that it's wrong?

Comment: It is wrong..............

Comment: Had he not seen.... in the conditional, when the condition is **see**.

Comment: *Had not **he** seen the car coming, there's no reason to think that someone else would not have.* There the condition is **he**.

Comment: The question hinges on what is being negated.

Comment: I have just added the source in the question @CookieMonster

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot that those types of conditionals follow this pattern: **had someone not done something, something else would (not) have happened**. That can be rewritten like this: **if someone hadn't done something, something else would (not) have happened**.